# Time Manager (QGIS) date format

Tags: qgis, timemanager

I've been through associated answers but cannot quite seem to find something which works!

I'm having trouble getting TimeManager to recognise a simple data field (this is in QGIS2 - but I've had this error in earlier versions). I have these fields formatted in what appears to be one of the acceptable formats:

[image]

... here is a screenshot of the field properties:

[image]

The format appears to be recognised in QGIS as I've worked out days difference between two dates (the "Time on Market" field shown in the image).

However ... I always end up with:
[image]

The Twitter.shp file works fine as a test, so I don't think this is an issue with the install / phyton conflict.

Any thoughts welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing support for fields of type date is a known issue: https://github.com/anitagraser/TimeManager/issues/37

It should work when the fields are converted to text.

Comment: Ha! Thanks ... I'd spent a good hour going over GitHub and cannot believe I didn't see that (missed it by THAT much). Thanks for the steer, works fine!